# Use of unassigned local variable 'folderPath'

Tags: c#

I have error:

> Use of unassigned local variable 'folderPath'

When I use this code:

```
string folderPath = folderPath.Substring(folderPath.IndexOf(@"\") + 1) + @"C:\test\" + "_converted";
```

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a string, and in that process you are trying to access it. That doesn't make sense.

If `folderPath` is an existing variable, either reuse the variable:

```
folderPath = folderPath ...
```

Or create a variable with another name:

```
string folderPath2 = folderPath ...
```